# I'm stuck on how to show this sequence monotonically decreasing: $U_{n+1}=U_{n}^{2}+\frac18$ and $U_0=\frac12$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

as infos I have :
$U_{0}=\frac{1}{2}$

$U_{n+1}=U_{n}^{2}+\frac{1}{8}$

I have already proved that $U_{n}$ is positive as the exercise requested but I still don't know how to use it with $U_{n+1}$ to show that $U_{n}$ is decreasing monotonically .
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Drawing [cobweb plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot) for the function $f(x)=x^2+\frac18$ might help you to get an idea how the sequence behaves. You can find pictures of cobweb plots in [several posts on this site](http://images.google.com/images?q=cobweb+plot+site:math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proceed by induction.

First verify that $u_1 < u_0$.

Next suppose $u_{n}<u_{n-1}$ for some positive integer n.

As you've already shown, the terms of the sequence are positive, hence
$$u_n<u_{n-1}$$
$$\Rightarrow {u_n}^2 < {u_{n-1}}^2$$
$$\Rightarrow {u_n}^2 + \frac{1}{8} < {u_{n-1}}^2 + \frac{1}{8}$$
$$\Rightarrow u_{n+1} < u_n$$
which completes the induction.

Comment: easy and simple forgot the $U_{n-1}$ tip well done

Answer (score 1):

We can prove it by induction .

$U_1=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}<\frac{1}{2}=U_{0}$

Let $n>1$, we assume that $U_{n-1}>U_{n}$, let s prove that $U_{n}>U_{n+1}$.

Given that  $U_{n-1}>U_{n}$, therefore $U_{n-1}^2>U_{n}^2$

$$U_{n+1}=U_n^2+\frac{1}{8}<U_{n-1}^2+\frac{1}{8}=U_n$$

Comment: oh the $U_{n-1}$ totally forgot abt it . thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to observe that $U_n<\frac{1}{2}$ for $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$

Let $u=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$ and we get $0<U_{n+1}-u=(U_n-u)(U_n+u)<(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4})(U_{n}-u)<U_n-u$

Comment: very original thank you